# saving and retrieving leaflet.js based non geographical map

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I have a SVG based non geographical layout with image overlay.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
var bounds = [[0,0], [1000,1000]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('uqm_map_full.png', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I traced out different shapes on top of this image.
[image: floorplan image with different shapes traced to identify different rooms of a building]

Now i want to retrieve all the shapes drawn, as a json object array and save it to database. Requirement is to replicate the same shapes later some point by fetching the json object array from database. Is it possible in leaflet.js? I want some thing like below

```
L.getObjectsArray(map) will give me 
var leafletAllShapesConfig = [Object1,Object2,Object3,Object4,Object5]
```

Now reading the object array i can be able to draw the same shapes like L.draw(leafletAllShapesConfig).
Is this possible and any in built method available to achieve the same? If not please give some idea how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Leaflet has a built in method: `L.GeoJson()`

Put your shapes into a featuregroup instead to the map.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
L.marker(latlng,options).addTo(fg);
```

Then you can get the geojson from the featuregroup:
`var gjson = fg.toGeoJSON()`

Now you can save this geojson as string with: `var str = JSON.stringify(gjson)`

To add the shapes back to the map use:

```
var json = JSON.parse(str);

fg.clearLayers() //To clean the map from the shapes
L.geoJSON(json, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        //Code
    }
}).addTo(fg);
```

Now you have your shapes back on your map, but without options/properties like color. GeoJson don't convert them too. You can solve this problem by looping through the layers in the featuregroup and add them manually to the gjson and add the layer.options to the gjson.properties.options and later by adding to the map, read the options from gjson out.

Comment: L.featureGroup() gives features list if a shape is added to featureGroup() programmatically while creating shape. If shape is added through a plugin e.g. "@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free" then i don't have control on it. How can i retrieve all the features on the SVG layer which are added from plugin tool bar. Is there any way to get all features as an array with all details?

Answer (score 0):

After some research over leaflet.js, i figured out an event "pm:drawend" from "geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free" plugin Github link https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman

```
map.on('pm:drawend', e => {
    console.log(e); //Gives array of all shapes including background image and SVG
});
```

Above snippet gives me an array of all shapes available(including background image and SVG container), the moment i finish adding any active shape. For reference including the output snippet here which served my purpose.
[image] 
By default leaflet includes background image as first item. Then follows the SVG container(where my map resides), then all shapes.Hope this will be use to some one else.